# Parse the fetched data from CassandraRDD efficiently and save it back to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I am newbie to Spark programming using Java. I have fetched the records in CassandraRDD

Person class consist of id,name,status,dept,....etc. 
According to dept I need to change the status of the person from default null to "randomValue" and many other transformations.

This parsing logic I need to implement and then save rdd back to cassandra.
Parsing logic using Map or mapPartitions or any other function which will parse each record and create RDD to save it back to Cassandra.

```
CassandraRDD<Person> rdd = javaFunctions(ctx).cassandraTable("keyspace1", "person_table", mapRowTo(Person.class)).rdd();
System.out.println("RDD : " + rdd.count());  //Currently It returns 1000 i.e. all records from table
/*
     Parsing logic will go here which will generate 'parsed_rdd'
*/
javaFunctions(parsed_rdd).writerBuilder("keyspace1", "person_table",mapToRow(Person.class)).saveToCassandra();  //Save it back to cassandra
```

Thanks. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please, remove "spark-java" tag, it's not related to Apache Spark, and this just confuses.

Comment: What exactly do you need to parse? rdd already contains parsed objects

Comment: Struggling to understand your question. Are you looking for a way to modify the value of the status column for each person? A table definition might help.